# Cast a partir do nome(String) do tipo do objeto

Tags: java, html

Recebo uma lista que tem vários tipos de HTMLElements. Eu preciso de uma lista NameValuePair, com nome e valor de cada objeto.
Então tenho essa função que recebe a lista:

```
    private List getValoresPost(List parametros){
    List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
    parametros.forEach(parametro -> {
        String type = parametro.getClass().getSimpleName();
        param.add(new NameValuePair(((HtmlHiddenInput) parametro).getNameAttribute(), ((HtmlHiddenInput) parametro).getValueAttribute()
        ));
    });
    return param;
}
```

Como eu disse, cada objeto é de um tipo diferente, o que eu pensei: pegar o nome do tipo desse objeto, e passar no parametro de cast. No lugar do (HtmlHiddenInput) eu colocar o type mas como objeto. Tem como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe `HtmlInput` ([link](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlInput.html)) é pai de várias classes utilizadas em formulários (elas que contém os métodos `.getNameAttribute()` e `.getValueAttribute()`), com exceção do `select`, então ao invés de fazer cast pelo nome da classe você pode fazer o seguinte para tratar o seu problema:

```
private List getValoresPost(List parametros){
    List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
    parametros.forEach(parametro -> {
        //como a lista não está tipada é bom checar os objetos com instanceof
        HtmlInput input = (HtmlInput) parametro;
        param.add(new NameValuePair(input.getNameAttribute(), input.getValueAttribute()));
        if(parametro.getClass().equals(HtmlSelect.class)) {
            //trata dados de um select (se você precisar)
        }
    });
    return param;
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! Muito obrigada.